# R- create new columns based on levels of a freq table variable

Tags: r

Hi I am new to R so please bear with me,

I have my data arranged like so,

```
   Length                            Seq     X  
       28   GTGCACCGCAAGTGCTTCTAAGAAGGAT    19 
       28   TGCACCGCAAGTGCTTCTAAGAAGGATC    18  
       29  GTGCACCGCAAGTGCTTCTAAGAAGGATC    19  
       29  GTGCACCGCAAGTGCTTCTAAGAAGGATC    19
```

and I used

```
count(dF, vars=c("Length", "X"))
```

to generate a freq table that looks like:

```
Length   X  freq
    28  15  160
    28  16  163
    28  17   21
    29  15  198
    29  16  410
    29  17  104
```

How can I rearrange the data so that it looks something like this?

```
Length    15    16    17   total
    28   160   163    21     344
    29   198   410   104     712
    30   205   614   393    1212
   Tot  2746  6564  2012   11322
```

(I know these values are wrong)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look like your example:

```
# your data
df<- data.frame(Length = c(28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29),
                X      = c(15, 16, 17, 15, 16, 17),
                freq   = c(160, 163, 21, 198, 410, 104))
```

use this function

```
require(reshape)
tabler <- function(a){
  b <- cast(a, Length~X)
  b <- cbind(b, rowSums(b))
  b <- rbind(b, colSums(b))
  colnames(b)[ncol(b)] <- b[nrow(b),1] <- "total"
  return(b)
}
tabler(df)
```

returns:

```
  Length  15  16  17 total
1     28 160 163  21   344
2     29 198 410 104   712
3  total 358 573 125  1056
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option is

```
addmargins(xtabs(freq~Length+X, df1))
#          X
#Length   15   16   17  Sum
#   28   160  163   21  344
#   29   198  410  104  712
#   Sum  358  573  125 1056
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Length = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L),
X = c(15L, 
16L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 17L), freq = c(160L, 163L, 21L, 198L, 410L, 
104L)), .Names = c("Length", "X", "freq"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```